# reading output of API in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, user-interface

I am calling one API in react. for that I am getting output in below format.

```
{
    "first_page_uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Messages.json?PageSize=50&Page=0",
    "end": 49,
    "previous_page_uri": null,
    "messages": [
        {
            "body": "",
            "num_segments": "1",
            "direction": "outbound-api",
            "from": "+12058557185",
            "date_updated": "Mon, 29 Aug 2022 09:07:47 +0000",
            "price": "-0.04410",
            "error_message": null,
            "uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Messages/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.json",
            "account_sid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "num_media": "0",
            "to": "+919823772514",
            "date_created": "Mon, 29 Aug 2022 09:07:42 +0000",
            "status": "delivered",
            "sid": "SMfa2e62cf71761db915657b02605bc689",
            "date_sent": "Mon, 29 Aug 2022 09:07:43 +0000",
            "messaging_service_sid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "error_code": null,
            "price_unit": "USD",
            "api_version": "2010-04-01",
            "subresource_uris": {
                "media": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Messages/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Media.json",
                "feedback": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Messages/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Feedback.json"
            }
        },
        {
            "body": "",
            "num_segments": "1",
            "direction": "outbound-api",
            "from": "+12058557185",
            "date_updated": "Mon, 29 Aug 2022 05:51:57 +0000",
            "price": "-0.04410",
            "error_message": null,
            "uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Messages/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.json",
            "account_sid": "AC9ab9e25e89eaa96c474e9a39867bb2f3",
            "num_media": "0",
            "to": "+919823772514",
            "date_created": "Mon, 29 Aug 2022 05:51:47 +0000",
            "status": "delivered",
            "sid": "SM5237fb62ff472b5e124fdd2ea073fffe",
            "date_sent": "Mon, 29 Aug 2022 05:51:47 +0000",
            "messaging_service_sid": "MG00d095919337aa95aeb5b74c8f0bd81c",
            "error_code": null,
            "price_unit": "USD",
            "api_version": "2010-04-01",
            "subresource_uris": {
                "media": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Messages/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Media.json",
                "feedback": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Messages/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Feedback.json"
            }
        },
        {
            "body": "",
            "num_segments": "1",
            "direction": "outbound-api",
            "from": "+12058557185",
            "date_updated": "Mon, 29 Aug 2022 05:24:09 +0000",
            "price": "-0.04410",
            "error_message": null,
            "uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Messages/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.json",
            "account_sid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "num_media": "0",
            "to": "+919727930925",
            "date_created": "Mon, 29 Aug 2022 05:24:05 +0000",
            "status": "delivered",
            "sid": "SM1528c06455368cfb7e00ab8283ed773c",
            "date_sent": "Mon, 29 Aug 2022 05:24:05 +0000",
            "messaging_service_sid": "MG00d095919337aa95aeb5b74c8f0bd81c",
            "error_code": null,
            "price_unit": "USD",
            "api_version": "2010-04-01",
            "subresource_uris": {
                "media": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Messages/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Media.json",
                "feedback": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Messages/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Feedback.json"
            }
        }
```

,`

I want to read differnet fields on it to perform some operation in UI.
for example I want to read `status`, `body`, `from` etc.

```
alert("Message is:"+JSON.stringify(response.data))
```

this line is giving output of an API properly.
but when I write

```
alert("Message is:"+JSON.stringify(response.data.messages))
alert("Message is:"+JSON.stringify(response.data.messages.from))
alert("Message is:"+JSON.stringify(response.data.messages[0].from))
```

I am getting undefined and exceptions. my goal is to print the value in UI for specific `status`.

Can somrebody help me on that.

I tried lot of options and googling but nothing helped. I am new to `javascript`

Answer (score 1):

Now this is a relatively complex topic for a beginner, let's start at the beginning.

## Objects

What you get from the api request is an object. An object has properties, like `first_page_uri`, `end`, and so on. In JSON that will look like this:

```json
{
  "first_page_uri": "this is a value",
  "end": 42
}
```

If you parsed the json string to a javascript object, like I assume you already have. You will have your object handle / variable. In your case that should be `response.data`.

With that handle you are able to get those object properties by accessing them using `.` after the handle and their name. For example you can display `first_page_uri` by writing this:

```js
alert(response.data.first_page_uri)
```

## Lists (Arrays)

Inside the response, there is a list. A list in JSON is represented like this:

```json
"my_list": [
  "a",
  "b",
  "c"
]
```

In this case the list has 3 values containing the strings `a`, `b` and `c`.

If you have a list in javascript, to get any of the values you can do the following:

```js
alert(my_list[index])
```

Where my_list is the list and index is a value between 0 for the first element `a` and in this case 2 for the last element `c`.

**Caution: we start counting from 0.**

To show `b` in an alert we would write:

```js
alert(my_list[1])
```

## Combination of both

The  attribute `messages` in your response is such a list. It contains not strings, but objects. Like so:

```json
{
  "messages": [
    {
      "body": "this is a message"
    },
    {
      "body": "this is another message"
    }
  ]
}
```

In this case if you wanted to retrieve the first message body and alert it, you would need to combine both patterns from above:

```js
alert(response.body.messages[0].body)
```

I am assuming your object is in `response.body`. We are accessing `messages` and then selecting the first with `[0]` and then selecting `body` from that message.

## Possible solutions

The problems you are encountering are probably the following:
alert is only able to show simple data types like string, number and so on. So trying to print out a whole list for example will not work.

I assume your other code is correct by the fact that you say that:

```js
alert("Message is:"+JSON.stringify(response.data))
```

works.

All you would need to do to fix your code, is to remove the second line:

```js
alert("Message is:"+JSON.parse(response.data.messages.from))
```

`.from` makes js try to access a property of a list. As discussed above. Objects have properties, lists do not. So react throws an exception.

Your other lines:

```js
alert("Message is:"+JSON.stringify(response.data.messages))
alert("Message is:"+JSON.stringify(response.data.messages[0].from))
```

should work. As they seem to be correct.

## The UI

Now regarding the UI part you are talking about...

If you are inside a react component, which would probably look somewhat like this:

```js
const ComponentName = (/* maybe stuff here */) => {
  // maybe a lot of stuff here
  return (
    /* this is the interesting part */
  )
}
```

You want to be looking for the `return` part.
Inside there you can write HTML-like code. A simple UI output to show all messages would be:

```js
const ComponentName = () => {
  // here you do your api stuff so you get the response variable
  const response;
  return (
    <>
      <h1>All messages:</h1>
      {
        response.body.messages.map((message) => (
          <p>{message.body}</p>
        ))
      }
    </>
  )
}
```

I did use a new thing here: the `map` function on a list. I put it in the recommended reading section below.

The part in the middle:

```js
<h1>All messages:</h1>
{
   response.body.messages.map((message) => (
     <p>{message.body}</p>
   ))
}
```

Is the important part. You can more or less put it anywhere in the return statement and it should show up.

## Recommended reading

To learn more you probably want to look up the following things:

- [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array?retiredLocale=de)
- [Array (map function)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map?retiredLocale=de)
- [Object (literals)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer?retiredLocale=de)
- [React (quick start tutorial)](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html)

## My thoughts (please ignore if unsuited)

If you are very new to javascript and this is a free time project. I would recommend taking it a step slower. While I do not want to discourage you from continuing with what you are doing, I assume that you can learn quicker and more effectively by stepping back and for example start with a HTML, CSS and JS only project without libraries. That should make you more comfortable in the concepts involved before jumping into a more complicated project. Especially if you do not have much or any experience with other languages.

A good start for that would be [this](https://github.com/adrianbautista/html-css-template) project. It does include jQuery, but you do not need to use it.

I wish you the best of luck going forward!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `JSON.parse` instead of `JSON.stringify`.

`JSON.parse` convert json string to js object and `JSON.stringify` do the reversed job.

So, your code should look like:

```
alert("Message is:"+JSON.parse(response.data.messages))
alert("Message is:"+JSON.parse(response.data.messages.from))
alert("Message is:"+JSON.parse(response.data.messages[0].from))
```

One more note here, to access nested property in JS object and avoid access anything from `undefined`, you should use JS optional chaining feature like below:

```
alert("Message is:"+JSON.parse(response?.data?.messages))
alert("Message is:"+JSON.parse(response?.data?.messages?.from))
```

The `?` take care of null check for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but first replace this api with your api

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users') // replace this api with your api
    .then((response) => {
      
      response.json().then((result) => {
        console.warn(result.data);
        this.setState({ data: result.data });
      });
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.data
          ? this.state.data.map((item, i) => (
              <div>
                <p>
                  {i} --- {item.body} {item.from}{' '}
                </p>
              </div>
            ))
          : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```